# Do Rust threads run at the same time in parallel? Documentation sounds like it does not

Tags: rust, concurrency

The extract below is from the rust documentation (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-01-threads.html#creating-a-new-thread-with-spawn). Why does it say "allowing a different thread to run". Aren't threads running concurrently ,i.e at the same time?

From the docs:

> The calls to thread::sleep force a thread to stop its execution for a
> short duration, allowing a different thread to run. The threads will
> probably take turns, but that isn’t guaranteed: it depends on how your
> operating system schedules the threads. In this run, the main thread
> printed first, even though the print statement from the spawned thread
> appears first in the code. And even though we told the spawned thread
> to print until i is 9, it only got to 5 before the main thread shut
> down.
>
> If you run this code and only see output from the main thread, or
> don’t see any overlap, try increasing the numbers in the ranges to
> create more opportunities for the operating system to switch between
> the threads.

its an informational question

Comment: Note that Rust uses native OS threads. As your docs quote says, "it depends on how your operating system schedules the threads".

Comment: Ok so i i understand correctly threads never execute in parallel no matter the OS on a single core machine, they just switch between each other. On multi core processor machine however threads actually can execute at the same time in parallel, thank @justinas